# Exception while deploying Tyrus websocket as OSGI bundle on Glassfish

Tags: osgi, glassfish-4, osgi-bundle, grizzly, tyrus

I have running tyrus websocket server standalone and without any problem but when i deploy OSGI bundle and try to start a tyrus server from bundleActivator class then getting exception otherwise when i run tyrus server locally it is running without any problem. Here is an exception when i deploy bundle:

```
[#|2017-08-01T15:33:00.262+0200|SEVERE|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=admin-listener(2);_TimeMillis=1501594380262;_LevelValue=1000;|Exception while loading the app : org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle com.mybundle.test-service [330].
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle com.mybundle.test-service [330].
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2196)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2064)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.startBundle(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.resume(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.start(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.InstanceDeployCommand.execute(InstanceDeployCommand.java:213)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:404)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandMultInMultOut(CommandResource.java:256)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ComponentProviderService.create(ComponentProviderService.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocketEngine.<init>(TyrusWebSocketEngine.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocketEngine.<init>(TyrusWebSocketEngine.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocketEngine$TyrusWebSocketEngineBuilder.build(TyrusWebSocketEngine.java:689)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.server.GrizzlyServerContainer$1.<init>(GrizzlyServerContainer.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.server.GrizzlyServerContainer.createContainer(GrizzlyServerContainer.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.spi.ServerContainerFactory.createServerContainer(ServerContainerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server.start(Server.java:199)
    at com.hospitality.sqlwebsocket.impl.WebSocketServer.initialize(WebSocketServer.java:28)
    at com.hospitality.sqlwebsocket.impl.WebSocketServerActivator.startServer(WebSocketServerActivator.java:30)
    at com.hospitality.sqlwebsocket.impl.WebSocketServerActivator.start(WebSocketServerActivator.java:18)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2146)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.DirectoryContent$EntriesEnumeration.listFilesRecursive(DirectoryContent.java:377)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.DirectoryContent$EntriesEnumeration.<init>(DirectoryContent.java:341)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.DirectoryContent.getEntries(DirectoryContent.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.EntryFilterEnumeration.<init>(EntryFilterEnumeration.java:59)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.findBundleEntries(Felix.java:1747)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.findBundleEntries(Felix.java:1735)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.findEntries(BundleImpl.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.OsgiRegistry.register(OsgiRegistry.java:436)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.OsgiRegistry.registerExistingBundles(OsgiRegistry.java:410)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.OsgiRegistry.hookUp(OsgiRegistry.java:403)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ServiceFinder.<clinit>(ServiceFinder.java:184)
    ... 97 more
```

Can someone tell me a reason why tyrus not starting from a bundleActivator class in OSGI

Comment: Are you trying to deploy Tyrus to GlassFish? It's highly likely you'll get into lots of problems because Tyrus is already a part of GlassFish so there will probably be conflicts

Comment: Well i resolved almost everything there :) Getting one problem only now as i am running tyrus as standalone server so if i use host name like localhost and deploy a websocket client on same machine it unable to connect. I tried with a IP address as well but no success. Have any idea how i can resolve this problem?